# Ansible: evaluate task variables with terminal command

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to output a task into terminal, with variables evaluated?

This is a very minimalist example, I want to execute an ansible command which will make the following task:

```
    - name: Create secret
      kubernetes.core.k8s:
        definition:
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Secret
          metadata:
            name: api-token
            namespace: '{{ kubernetes_namespace }}'
          type: Opaque
        wait: true
```

To be displayed in this readable format:

```
    - name: Create secret
      kubernetes.core.k8s:
        definition:
          apiVersion: v1
          kind: Secret
          metadata:
            name: api-token
            namespace: kube-system
          type: Opaque
        wait: true
```

Thank you.

Comment: You mean, you like to debug at runtime? Like with [Ansible Task Debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_debugger.html) or [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) or [Using `--check-mode`/`check_mode:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html)or [How to debug Ansible issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417079/)

Answer (score 1):

That's actually quite tricky as far as I know.

The first step is to make the whole output more readable using [`community.general.yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-yaml-callback) stdout callback or setting [`callback_result_format = yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html#parameter-result_format) for the default callback (note that these two options are not equal):

```ini
; ansible.cfg

[defaults]
callback_result_format = yaml
stdout_callback = community.general.yaml
```

Then, the simplest (and kind of recommended for this case) way will be just run the playbook with `-vvv` which will show the module arguments as well. It will output not only the arguments you've set, but **all the values** used by the module (output is redacted for brevity):

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  invocation:
    module_args:
      ...
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        metadata:
          name: api-token
          namespace: test-namespace
        type: Opaque
      ...
      wait: true
      ...
```

You can also use [`community.general.selective`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/selective_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-selective-callback) callback to display only the tasks tagged with `print_action` to reduce the output.

Another obvious solution (spoiler - will not work in this particular case) could be to register the return object of the module and display its `invocation` with `debug` afterwards:

```yaml
- some_module:
    some_arg1: value1
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result.invocation
```

But [`kubernetes.core.k8s`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html) module does not return [`invocation`](https://https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#invocation) as part of its return object. Another major drawback of this method is that it will not work if the task fails.

So, the idea that will work but [**is not recommended due to security reasons**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe) is to define the module arguments in a variable and log them before the invocation:

```yaml
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    kubernetes_namespace: test-namespace
  tasks:
    - name: Create K8s secrets
      vars:
        task_args:
          definition:
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Secret
            metadata:
              name: api-token
              namespace: '{{ kubernetes_namespace }}'
            type: Opaque
          wait: true
      block:
        - name: List the 'kubernetes.core.k8s' arguments
          debug:
            var: task_args

        - name: Create secret
          kubernetes.core.k8s: '{{ task_args }}'
```

This gives:

```
PLAY [Test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [List the 'kubernetes.core.k8s' arguments] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  task_args:
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret
      metadata:
        name: api-token
        namespace: test-namespace
      type: Opaque
    wait: true

TASK [Create secret] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Using a variable for a task's 'args' is unsafe in some situations (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe)
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible_collections.kubernetes.core.plugins.module_utils.k8s.exceptions.CoreException: Could not create API client: Invalid kube-config file. Expected object with name  in /Users/alexander/.kube/config/contexts list
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: 'Could not create API client: Invalid kube-config file. Expected object with name  in /Users/alexander/.kube/config/contexts list'
```

You can also control when this will actually be logged. For example, the following task will print the variable only if the playbook was run with `-v`:

```yaml
        - name: List the 'kubernetes.core.k8s' arguments
          debug:
            var: task_args
            verbosity: 1
```

So, to sum up, I would stick to just logging the important variables before the task execution (if it's important for the playbook users) without bulk passing them to the module, and/or using verbose logging or even [debugger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_debugger.html) during the development as suggested by [@U880D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771046/u880d).