# Debugging fails when reading input from file

Tags: python, bash, pipe, cat, pdb

`pdb` exits with a `BdbQuit` exception when I try to use it within my script `main.py` which is run as follows:

```
cat input_file.txt | python main.py
```

You can reproduce the error using the following example:

1) Create a file `i.txt` containing the following:

```
1 2 3
```

2) Create a file `main.py` containing the following:

```py
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
print(a, b, c)
```

3) Use the following command:

```
cat i.txt | python main.py
```

and you'll get something similar to this

```
> /path/to/main.py(3)<module>()
-> print(a, b, c)
(Pdb) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(a, b, c)
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(a, b, c)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

any clue ?

Comment: pdb can't be interactive if you are feeding data to stdin.

Comment: Basically the data from your input_file went to pdb.

Comment: Potential solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101777/run-pdb-without-stdin-stdout-using-fifo

Comment: @jordanm Yes I know! ... let me reformulate my question, can I use them both at the same time? If not, what should I change and how?

Comment: If you instantiate the debugger as `pdb.Pdb(...)`, you can set alternate stdin/stdout pipes. Several ways to do this are in the linked answer.

Comment: @tdelaney Well, I found an easier solution :)
```sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')```
Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178751/use-pdb-set-trace-in-a-script-that-reads-stdin-via-a-pipe

Comment: @Stoufa - That's interesting. I think it works because you've consumed everything you want from stdin before fiddling with pdb. Glad you found that one.

Comment: @Stoufa - I put `pdb.Pdb(None, open('/dev/tty', 'r'), open('/dev/tty', 'w')).set_trace()` before `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())` and was able to step through it.

Comment: @tdelaney perfect ✌️